# Shortcut image of html page

Tags: html

For my personal use i'm creating a website where i wish to give a shortcut image which will be displayed in the browser's tab. I use the following code

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="image/logo/logo.png"/>
```

But the problem is when i'm using any other browser except firefox the shortcut image is not being displayed.I fire fox it is fine but in all other case it is just showing blank.Any idea how to solve it?

Comment: What other browsers have you tried?

Comment: png not support in old browser. Use ico instead png. Also try to use favicon.ico name of icon and place it in root of your application for cross browser support

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the type, and have the href point to a .ico file.

The following works:

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/ico" href="/favicon.ico" />
```

Answer (score 0):

***It's recommended to use `.ico` file instead of `.png`***

you can convert any file to `.ico` from here **[FavIcon from Pics](http://favicon.htmlkit.com/favicon/)**

Then try with this:

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="your_file.ico" />
```